# Horizontal RecyclerView items in center

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, center, itemtouchhelper

I want to set Horizontal RecyclerView with 4 items in it. Items should appear in center of the screen. Each item has a fixed height and width. I want to place all items in center and make my RecyclerView match_parent. What I achieved is using wrap_content to RecyclerView. But if give match_parent to recyclerView all items appear from left not in center. But I want all items in center of the screen with match_parent recylcerView.

Here is what I am doing:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerDragDrop"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">
```

Item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgContainer"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/tube_delete"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
final ContainerItemAdapter mAdapter = new ContainerItemAdapter(MainActivity.this, containers, this, mLayoutManager);
        ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback =
                new EditItemTouchHelperCallback(mAdapter);
        mItemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        mItemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerContainer);
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ContainerItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                showToastLay(position);
            }
        });
        mRecyclerContainer.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

With above code all my items appear in middle of the screen because my recyclerview is in center and has a wrap_content property.

But why I need my RecyclerView match_parent?

I am using RecyclerView's Drag and Drop functionality by using ItemTouchHelper classes. Now, whenever I drag any item to end of recyclerview that item start disappering from screen or we can say item doesn't drag untill the screen width. I want my items to drag until screen width or it should stop dragging whenever item reaches recyclerview's width. If I give match parent to my recyclerview then drag works fine but it shows all items from left of the screen not in center and I want all my items to show in center of the screen.

Please let me know if there is any solution available.

Thanks!

As I am using drag and drop

Comment: `android:gravity="center"` to the recyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Try the column item fill the width of the column while centering everything inside:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="180dp"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="4dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/movie_column_photo"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/movie_column_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

it helps you

Comment: I posted my item xml file. Can you please tell me how to achieve in that? I am not getting you properly that's why.

Comment: Like image view text view anything you want align in gravity center as mention in my xml, and don't add the recycler view  gravity just  you can add scrol horizontal

Comment: If you set match_parent to your item layout file it will fill whole screen into only 1 item. So item layout file's parent should not be match_parent.